# PostgreSQL an efficient way to select using IN and OR

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to select a table in which I a have 3 or 4 columns that I want to match against an array/list with 1,000 or 10,000 (passed as parameter using a function) but it takes too much time, I readed that using indexes might help but still there ir poor performance during Query.

Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT 
"id", "parcel_number", "alternate_parcel_number", "parcel_tax_number"
FROM "addresses"
WHERE 
    "parcel_number" IN ('A080100', ... 'A0368895224')
    OR "alternate_parcel_number" IN ('A080100', ... 'A0368895224')
    OR "parcel_tax_number" IN ('A080100', ... 'A0368895224');
```

With an array/list of 1000 lines it takes about 2 min to return results.

Thanks.

Comment: If that list is full of numbers in another table, please use a `SELECT` query instead of a list. Reconsider your problem. There's a reason that such a practice is frowned upon: it eats up too many resources and makes your query run slowly.

Comment: What does this have to do with `python-3.x` ?

Comment: What's the whole context of this? Is that the query that's taking too long, or is it in combination with another procedure (like an ORM in between, or extracting the parameters from somewhere else)?

Comment: @SebastianPalma yes, the query is taking too long originally I was using Django ORM but I'm looking for a solution using raw sql.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution on a website and change to VALUES gives a huge speed improvement.

URL: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/

```sql
SELECT 
"id", "parcel_number", "alternate_parcel_number", "parcel_tax_number"
FROM "addresses"
WHERE 
    "parcel_number" = ANY (VALUES ('A080100'), ... ('A0368895224'))
    OR "alternate_parcel_number" = ANY (VALUES ('A080100'), ... ('A0368895224'))
    OR "parcel_tax_number" = ANY (VALUES ('A080100'), ... ('A0368895224'));
```

Comment: You might want to try creating your own chain of OR conditions for each value to see if it improves somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It's not advisable to pass 10.000 values as parameters to a function. When I need to do that, my solution was:

1. Insert all parameters on a temporary table and associate all of them to a key value:

   CREATE TEMP_TABLE (PARAM_KEY INT, PARCEL_NO INT);
2. Pass only the key value to the function
3. Run the query:

   SELECT id, parcel_number, alternate_parcel_number, parcel_tax_number
   FROM "addresses" join temp_table on parcel_number = temp_param
   WHERE PARAM_key = :param_key

   UNION

   SELECT id, parcel_number, alternate_parcel_number, parcel_tax_number
   FROM "addresses" join temp_table
   on alternate_parcel_number = temp_param
   WHERE PARAM_key = :param_key

   UNION

   SELECT id, parcel_number, alternate_parcel_number, parcel_tax_number
   FROM "addresses" join temp_table on parcel_tax_number = temp_param
   WHERE PARAM_key = :param_key;